# How do I record audio and locate a certain frequency in Android (java)

Tags: java, android, android-audiorecord

I know that there are many questions about this, but none of them give a clear answer. The following is the code I'm using to try and make this work.

```
package com.nonexistent.rs.sometestthing;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static int calculate(int sampleRate, short [] audioData){

        int numSamples = audioData.length;
        int numCrossing = 0;
        for (int p = 0; p < numSamples-1; p++)
        {
            if ((audioData[p] > 0 && audioData[p + 1] <= 0) ||
                    (audioData[p] < 0 && audioData[p + 1] >= 0))
            {
                numCrossing++;
            }
        }

        float numSecondsRecorded = (float)numSamples/(float)sampleRate;
        float numCycles = numCrossing/2;
        float frequency = numCycles/numSecondsRecorded;

        return (int)frequency;
    }
    public void getpitch(View v){
        int channel_config = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
        int format = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
        int sampleSize = 8000;
        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleSize, channel_config, format);
        AudioRecord audioInput = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, sampleSize, channel_config, format, bufferSize);
        TextView txtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);





        short[] audioBuffer = new short[bufferSize];
        audioInput.startRecording();
        audioInput.read(audioBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        //recorder.startRecording();
        //recorder.read(audioBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
        txtview.setText(""+calculate(8000,audioBuffer));
    }

}
```

So that's all my code, and it mostly works. The problem is that the textview displays 0 after I click a button. (You can see that the function getpitch() responds to a click on a button.) Also, the calculate() function is from another similar question, though it doesn't work.

I'm fairly sure that it *does* start recording, and *does* write it to the array. Problem is, I don't know how to analyze that array to get a frequency, or rather, find a certain frequency.

Anyone know how? Please try not to give extremely complex answers, as I am very new to this.

Comment: what does `calculate(8000,audioBuffer)` give you? 0?

Comment: Yes, it does give 0, which is why the textview says 0 at the end of all this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by increasing the buffer size to 176000 bytes and multiplying that number by the number of seconds I wanted to record. I also added a stop() and a release() call. The frequency measuring part is wildly inaccurate (a little less than 1/2 the frequency I tested with) , but it probably could be calibrated for.

Answer (score 0):

You have several potentially problematic points there:

1. The `sampleRate` (=`sampleSize` in getpitch) you chose is 8000. In the documentation of the constructor (which the documentation of `getMinBufferSize` refers to) you have:

   > Class constructor. Though some invalid parameters will result in an IllegalArgumentException exception, other errors do not. Thus you should call getState() immediately after construction to confirm that the object is usable.
   >
   > sampleRateInHz - int: the sample rate expressed in Hertz. 44100Hz is currently the only rate that is guaranteed to work on all devices, but other rates such as 22050, 16000, and 11025 may work on some devices.
   >
   > ([Source here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read(short[],%20int,%20int,%20int)))

   which to me raises the question if the construction even gave you a working `AudioRecord`. You should add the mentioned check just after the construction to see if that is the case.

-- After checking (see bottom of this answer) - you do have a problem with the state of the AudioRecord, even if it's just on some devices (it crashed in mine, and I understand it didn't in yours) --

2. Unlike with a very similar method that accepts an additional `readMode` parameter, here you cannot specify if you want the method to block or not. Additionally, the documentation doesn't (at this moment) include the information regarding the behaviour of this method in this sense - whether it blocks and wait for the recording to complete or returns immediately with as much audio as possible (look in the documentation of the other [read(short[], int, int, int) method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read(short[],%20int,%20int,%20int))). So if the behaviour is the latter one here it is possible that calling the method one line after calling `startRecording()` doesn't actually allow it any time whatsoever to record and it then just returns no data at all. To check that - capture the returned value from the `read(short[], int, int)` call. This value will tell you whether any data was read. Log it and check. Also note the possible error codes you might get there (again - [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#read(short[],%20int,%20int))).
3. I'm not sure you are using the right code for what you want in the `calculate` method. This implementation is a very straightforward way to calculate the frequency of a sinusoidal wave, meaning it will give you the frequency if you record a pure note/pitch/frequency. For actual recorded audio, which most likely has a superposition of lots of frequencies (meaning they add up to the complex wave you record). I'm not sure what you want from a realisticly recorded wave like that when you say "locate a certain frequency" but I would point you to Fourier decomposition/analysis. Sorry - you wanted it to be kept simple, but I think that is the right direction. You might be happy with your current code if you do actually record a single note (for tuning a guitar maybe) but I would check that this implementation is not over-simplistic for your purpose.

I wanted to check it myself so I opened a new project with your code in it (and added the `onCreate` to attach the xml to the java). I got the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
>
> at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:894)
>
> at com.trysoq_audiorecord.MainActivity.getpitch(MainActivity.java:58)

After adding a log for `audioInput.getState()` just after the construction of `audioInput` I got 0, which according to the documentation means UNINITIALIZED. So I think my #1 suggestion is at least one problem here.

Comment: 1. Ok, I made the sampleRate 44100.  
2. Still working on that. 3.Is the calculate() method good enough if I play a series of perfect sine waves (multiple frequencies played in a sequence) with another phone?

Comment: Re 3 - no. If you record while the other phone plays only one note it's probably fine, but if you record white it pays a sequence of different frequencies I think it will give you a frequency that is the weighted average of the captured frequencies (the weights being proportional to the faction of the time they were played out of the entire recorded time).

Comment: Oh, and the startRecording part is non-blocking, according to the log, but doesn't say uninitialized.

Comment: I recommend following my suggestion in the answer regarding that - save the returned it from `read` and log it to see if you get any data at all (if it's >0)

Comment: I added a stop() and release() call after the read(), and if I do that, I do get random numbers. Playing a 4000 hz sound with another device gives readings of 40-150, which doesn't seem right.

Answer (score -1):

*Use Below Code*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

MediaRecorder recorder;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();

}

public void init(){

recorder=new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
recorder.setOutputFile("/storage/sdcard0/android_730_new.amr");

recorder.setMaxDuration(10000);

recorder.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {

    @Override
    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {

        if(what==recorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "10 seconds recording completed....", 2000).show();

            recorder.stop();

        }
    }
});


try{
    recorder.prepare();
}catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}



}





public void start(View v){

    recorder.start();
}


public void stop(View v){

    recorder.stop();
}
```

}